# VSCode v1.43 remote ssh cannot connect. v1.42 works

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access

I am connecting to a CENTOS 7.4  machine from my MAC using **remote ssh** extension. Everything was working fine in **v1.42**. I updated to **v1.43** yesterday and now VSCode cannot connect. I get following error and it 'hangs' till I select close remote connection. I switched back to v1.42 and it works. Anyone else seen this?

```
[11:48:35.614] stderr> Authenticated to 172.18.116.204 ([172.18.116.204]:22).
[11:48:35.704] > Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
[11:48:35.707] > Thus no job control in this shell.
[11:48:36.308] stderr> stty: 
[11:48:36.308] stderr> standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[11:48:36.309] stderr> 
[11:48:38.151] stderr> stty: 
[11:48:38.152] stderr> standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[11:48:38.152] > ready: 552eb5fb743e
[11:48:38.180] > Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017
[11:48:38.180] Platform: linux
[11:48:38.246] stderr> bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
[11:48:38.246] stderr> bash: line 1: `then'
[11:48:38.247] stderr> function: Command not found.
[11:48:38.247] > 552eb5fb743e: running
[11:48:38.248] stderr> COMMIT_ID=78a4c91400152c0f27ba4d363eb56d2835f9903a: Command not found.
[11:48:38.248] stderr> EXTENSIONS=: Command not found.
[11:48:38.249] stderr> TELEMETRY=: Command not found.
[11:48:38.263] stderr> export: Permission denied.
[11:48:38.282] stderr> ALLOW_CLIENT_DOWNLOAD=1: Command not found.
[11:48:38.282] stderr> VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER: Undefined variable.
[11:48:38.283] stderr> _lock: Command not found.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an open issue in VSCode Remote-SSH version 0.50.0. See [Issue #2527](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2527).

The way I resolved it was to downgrade to version 0.49.0.

1. In VSCode, Ctrl+Shift+X to open extensions
2. Click the **Manage** icon next to the **Remote - SSH** extension
3. Click **Install Another Version...** from the options
4. Select the version to install (0.49.0)

I also recommend disabling the Extensions Auto Update in settings so this type of thing doesn't happen in the future with this or any other extensions.

Comment: it works ! thanks ! i was going crazy trying to use notepad inside WinScp

Comment: Great buddy, I was facing this issue since long and wasted a lot of time. You are great!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is NOT a issue of VSCode(v1.42 or 1.43). You can try to downgrade Remote-SSH extension to version 0.49.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by [Cleaning up the VS Code Server on the remote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-up-the-vs-code-server-on-the-remote). No uninstalling, no downgrading...

Simply:

1. Close VS Code
2. SSH into the remote using any other way, and run the commands from the link:

```sh
kill -9 `ps ax | grep "remoteExtensionHostAgent.js" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
kill -9 `ps ax | grep "watcherService" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server # Or ~/.vscode-server-insiders
```

3. Open VS Code again (it will re-install the remote server).

**EDIT:**
Running VS Code v1.43, Remote-SSH extension v0.50, on Windown 10.
Remote machine is CentOS 7